# my layout can not be referenced from getView using layoutinflater?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, layout-inflater

I do not why I can not refer to my layout as a resource when using `Layoutinflater` in `getView`?

below are the `getView` method of my adapter class and the contents of the layout that i want to refernce using `convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.XXXXXX, null);`

**Adapter class**:

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItemStructure> itemsList;

private void NavDrawerItemStructure(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItemStructure> itemsList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.itemsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.itemsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout., root)
    }       
    return convertView;            
 }
 }
```

**list_view_item_design.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what error occur using `layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_design, null);` ?

Comment: are you passing context from your activity to your adapter class?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no errors, i just can not reference or call my layout "the one posted above" in my inflater. the layout exists but i can not refernce it

Comment: @Anjali yes, please have a ook at the code, i posted the adapter class instead of just posted the getView method

Comment: might be the case your adapter file is importing wrong R file. check the import

Comment: just a copy/paste thing or Do You really have written R.layout. ? Without layout name?

Comment: @Anjali i realy can not understandit, when i type "R.layout", automaticall, eclipse import .R

Comment: Or you could clean your project and IDE by restarting.

Comment: there might be some issue in your res folder. Clean your project and check in console for any error

Comment: i think u dont need adapter...cos only textview is there in ur adapter xml..

Comment: what is NavDrawerItemStructure?

Comment: Can you post the imports in this file?

Answer (score 0):

Change this part;

```
LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout., root)
```

with this one;

```
LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.song_adapter_cell, null);
```

And try again.